# Content of uiview from nib is outside container

Tags: ios, uiview, nib, ibdesignable

I want to insert a custom UIView in a custom UITableViewCell.
I have created a nib file with some actions and I want to put this view at the bottom of my cell but the content displays on the top of my cell. Why ?
[image]

**EDIT :**

Code of my view :

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    xibSetup()
}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()

    // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
    view.frame = bounds

    // Make the view stretch with containing view
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
    // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
    addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "viewActionsTimeline", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to put the view from the nib file into your prototype cell?

Comment: probably because you didn't specify its frame/constraints.

Comment: Constraints are good. I have put my code in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem.
I put this line :

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider your view as below

[image: Consider your view as below]

Code for View. Make your class `@IBDesignable`

```
@IBDesignable
class BottomView: UIView {
    var view: UIView!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

    func xibSetup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()

        // use bounds not frame or it'll be offset
        view.frame = bounds

        // Make the view stretch with containing view
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        // Adding custom subview on top of our view (over any custom drawing > see note below)
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "BottomView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }
}
```

Now in your cell select your bottom view and in **identity inspector change the class of view** to this view i.e BottomView in this case.

[image]

**OR**

In your code add your custom view in bottom view of cell

```
let  bottomView = BottomView(frame: cellBottomView.frame)
cellBottomView.addSubview(bottomView)
```

Comment: I really want the view to stand apart so that if I add a button, it will add to all my cells at once

Comment: I think this solution will help you.